# SSL on IIS6/7 restrictions and GoDaddy or other hosting provider

Tags: ssl, ip, hosting

I'm trying to understand how hosting providers implementing the support for SSL.

As I know (i found many resources on web to confirm this), it's impossible to assign a SSL for more than one domain on IIS, if these domains sharing the same EP (IP:PORT).
If so, how then GoDaddy (on other hosting provider) allows me to set SSL for my site?
Does they provide IP for each hosting account? Does they provide virtual server with IP and IIS?
The question is totally theoretical and just for understanding the technology...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an SSL on Go Daddy shared hosting you are assigned a dedicated IP.